# Should this PDF form file be fillable?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to fill out a PDF form file, but I can't enter anything in the yellow fields. I've tried Ubuntu Linux with Adobe Reader 9.4.2 and Evince 3.2.1, however, I'm not sure this is a problem with the applications rather than too restricted PDF file. Can anyone help me to interpret the document properties?

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot share the PDF file due to privacy reasons, but I'm happy to try any known fillable PDF form you can link to. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your PDF to this one: http://www.dkb.de/download/scheckeinreichung_inlandsschecks.pdf

Comment: Thanks! It works and shows the same properties as the one in question, so I guess this is just an issue with the document.